# Exponential function in GNU multiple precision arithmetic library (GMP)

Tags: gmp, exponential

I would like to compute the exponential of a float in the GMP library. Namely, given

`mpf_t x`

I would like to compte exp(x). I could not find this function in the GMP documentation. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: Do not use mpf_t for new code, use mpfr_t from the MPFR library. It provides exponential and many other functions.

Comment: MPFR works, thank you.